# How i can change keystore(.jks) Organizational unit, Country in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I want to change key-store detail of live android application.
is there any way to change that jks properties?

Comment: There is no way you can do so

Comment: You can't. They are final once keystore is created.